# Primary shard unassigned after adding more nodes (or node lost)

Tags: elasticsearch, timeout

Some indices primary shard is in unassigned status, it shows a red indicator.  If I run `GET _cluster/allocation/explain`, it will give the details like:

```
"unassigned_info": {
    "reason": "ALLOCATION_FAILED",
    "at": "2018-06-19T00:29:17.781Z",
    "failed_attempts": 5,
    "delayed": false,
    "details": "failed to create shard, failure IOException[failed to obtain in-memory shard lock]; nested: ShardLockObtainFailedException[[log_2018_05][10]: obtaining shard lock timed out after 5000ms]; ",
    "allocation_status": "deciders_no"
}
```

This happened twice in our production environment.  Once was when multiple data nodes were lost in one network disconnection.  Another time was when we added 2 more data nodes into the environment.

How should this be handled?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the primary shard is in unassigned status.

Elastic's support suggested the below API call, which will retry the shard allocation that has failed before:

```
 POST _cluster/reroute?retry_failed
```

That should make the unassigned primary shards reroute to available nodes, and the cluster should turn from red to yellow status *(which means all primary shards are ok, replica are not ready)*